# How do I add a custom inline admin widget in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This is easy for non-inlines. Just override the following in the your admin.py AdminOptions:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'photo':
        kwargs['widget'] = AdminImageWidget()
        return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
    return super(NewsOptions,self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field,**kwargs)
```

I can't work out how to adapt this to work for inlines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works exactly the same way.  The TabularInline and StackedInline classes also have a formfield_for_dbfield method, and you override it the same way in your subclass.

Comment: Doh! I was over-complicating things and fiddling around with InlineFormsetFactory and the like!

Answer (score 8):

Since Django 1.1, formfield_overrides is also working

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.ImageField: {'widget': AdminImageWidget},
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it seems to want to add a new field when default= is set on something on the inline.

Answer (score 3):

Working example:

```
class PictureInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Picture_Gallery
    extra = 3
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'name':
            kwargs['widget'] = MyWidget()
        return super(PictureInline,self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field,**kwargs)
```

Comment: `formfield_for_dbfield` is not a documented API