# In GeoDjango, use GeoModelAdmin as a StackedInline in the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, geodjango

I am trying to use the GeoModelAdmin as a StackedInline in the Django Admin panel.

I have seen these two similar questions:

- [GeoDjango: Can I use OSMGeoAdmin in an Inline in the User Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32037375/1060339)
- [django admin inlines with GeoModelAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4720247/1060339)

The answer that recommends inheriting from *both* `GeoModelAdmin` *and* `StackedInline` almost works.  The following code:

**models.py:**

```
class SomeGeometry(gis_models.Model):
  geometry = gis_models.GeometryField(blank=False, null=False)
  some_model = models.ForeignKey("somemodel", blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="geometries")

class SomeModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**admin.py:**

```
class SomeGeometryAdminInline(gis_admin.GeoModelAdmin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = SomeGeometry
    extra = 0
    fields = (
        "geometry",
    )


    def __init__(self, parent_model, admin_site):

        # InlineModelAdmin.__init__
        self.admin_site = admin_site
        self.parent_model = parent_model
        self.opts = self.model._meta
        self.has_registered_model = admin_site.is_registered(self.model)


        # BaseModelAdmin.__init__
        overrides = copy.deepcopy(FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS)
        for k, v in self.formfield_overrides.items():
            overrides.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
        self.formfield_overrides = overrides


@admin.register(SomeModel)
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("name",)
    inlines = (SomeGeometryAdminInline, )
```

Correctly shows an editable geometry widget.  But there is no "add another model" link at the bottom of the inline formset.

Any hints as to how to get that link back?

---

If I explicitly set

```
formfield_overrides = {
  gis_fields.GeometryField: {
    "widget": gis_widgets.OpenLayersWidget
  }
}
```

Then the widget looks like this:

[image]

But I *want* it to look like this:

[image]

*(notice the controls in the top-right to allow me to modify the geometry)*

Comment: Did you try the solution proposed by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57386357/548562?

Comment: @IainShelvington - Thanks, I have.  If I do that, I get a pretty geometry widget, but it doesn't look like the one in the default GeoModelAdmin.  I'll update my question to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

There should be used OSMWidget and here is how I have used the following solution:
[How do I add a custom inline admin widget in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433251/how-do-i-add-a-custom-inline-admin-widget-in-django)

My model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Territory(models.Model):
    poly = models.PolygonField(_('Polygon, borders of territory.'))
    location = models.PointField(_('Location, point on the map.'))
```

My inline model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import OSMWidget

class TerritoryStackedInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Territory
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name in ('poly', 'location'):
            kwargs['widget'] = OSMWidget
        return super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field,**kwargs)
```

The OSMWidget overrides template to "gis/openlayers-osm.html" where does following override of basic layer is happen:

```
{% block base_layer %}
var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()});
{% endblock %}
```

without it the basic layer code looks like this(template used "gis/openlayers.html"):

```
{% block base_layer %}
    var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            attributions: "NASA Worldview",
            maxZoom: 8,
            url: "https://map1{a-c}.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-webmerc/" +
                 "BlueMarble_ShadedRelief_Bathymetry/default/%7BTime%7D/" +
                 "GoogleMapsCompatible_Level8/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg"
        })
    });
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see there is different source.